# Redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)/(.*) haveg/employer.php?msg_id=$1
```

It works fine when i use

```
http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title
or
http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003/
```

The problem is here `http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003` because i removed the forward slash at the end. it gives page not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)/?(.*) haveg/employer.php?msg_id=$1

I think adding a questionmark should allow it to match.

Comment: That will rewrite the URL `http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003message` to `http://localhost/employer.php?msg_id=message`. Not very clean

Comment: @Borodin - Aside from your case being a hand-edited url which maybe isn't important to support,  I don't think you are correct anyway. The $1 group will still be 7003 because it will stop matching at the first character not in the set [0-9], and so that will cause msg_id=7003. Your solution however fails to match the case where there are additional path elements, which does not match the intent of the original expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last line to

```
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)([^0-9]*) haveg/employer.php?msg_id=$1
```

This should accept both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add another `RewriteRule` to make your intention clear. In this code the first rule handles the case when the URL ending with digits followed by an optional slash (when the `msg_id` query field is blank), and the second applies where there is a message following the digits.

```
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)/?$ haveg/employer.php?msg_id=
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ haveg/employer.php?msg_id=$1 [L]
```